# Get object literal top level name in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am using lodash to group by

```
_.groupBy(_.flatten(this.postReleaseArr), 'module');
```

which returns

[image]

How do i return the names **"Post Release Support"**,**"Round Table"**,**"VOD Meeting"**
in the *ngFor ?

My Html is

```
<div *ngFor="let item of postReleaseArr">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Which just returns

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that your object comes from an array of objects (JSON), use following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of postReleaseArr">
   {{item['Post Release Support']}} - {{item['Round Table']}} - {{item['VOD Meeting']}}
</div>
```

Comment: @gerdi My pleasure. Good luck with your app.